# what is the best way to convert the values in this data set from strings to int

Tags: javascript, string, int, dataset, converters

This is my dataset:

```
data_p = [
[   {"key":"Device_Model","value":"test_model"},
    {"key":">20MB/30","value":"11"},
    {"key":">200MB/30","value":"33"},
    {"key":">2048MB/30","value":"10"},
    {"key":">5120MB/30","value":"55"},
    {"key":">10240MB/30","value":"10"}
],
[{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B670"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"9"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"8"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"2"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}],
[{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B680"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}],
[{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B810"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"5"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"4"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"1"}],
[   {"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B900"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"4"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"4"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}]]
```

This is the way I have done, but I am wondering is reduce, map or filter a better way to do it. I mean should I be using a for loop inside a forEach function? I also don't like the i<6 as this is very static what if there was more than 6 in the dataset?

```
data_p.forEach(function(d){for(i=1; i<6; i++){console.log(d[i].value); d[i].value=+d[i].value}})
```

This will give me:

```
    data_p = [
    [   {"key":"Device_Model","value":"test_model"},
        {"key":">20MB/30","value":11},
        {"key":">200MB/30","value":33},
        {"key":">2048MB/30","value":10},
        {"key":">5120MB/30","value":55},
        {"key":">10240MB/30","value":10}
    ],
...
```

**So the question is is there a better way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate all elements. Check if value is numeric (isNaN) then update the property

```js
var data_p = [
[   {"key":"Device_Model","value":"test_model"},
    {"key":">20MB/30","value":"11"},
    {"key":">200MB/30","value":"33"},
    {"key":">2048MB/30","value":"10"},
    {"key":">5120MB/30","value":"55"},
    {"key":">10240MB/30","value":"10"}
],
[{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B670"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"9"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"8"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"2"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}],
[{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B680"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}],
[{"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B810"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"5"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"4"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"1"}],
[   {"key":"Device_Model","value":"0P6B900"},
{"key":">20MB/30","value":"4"},
{"key":">200MB/30","value":"4"},
{"key":">2048MB/30","value":"1"},
{"key":">5120MB/30","value":"23"},
{"key":">10240MB/30","value":"23"}]]



data_p.forEach(list => 
       list.forEach(pair => 
            !isNaN(pair.value) && (pair.value = Number(pair.value))
       )
);

console.log(data_p);
```

Comment: tks, can you just briefly explain what it does? what is pair, =>, and list? tks

Comment: well, I just gave parameter names to make it readable. Your root data structure contains array of objects. They are kind of data lists so I named each of them as "list". And the list contents contains key and value properties. Theorically they are kind of key value pairs. So, I named each of them as "pair".

Answer (score 0):

The are many ways of doing this.

E.G. Update `data_p` in place using `array.forEach` and `array.reduce`

```
data_p.forEach( function(a) {
    a.reduce( function( ignore, obj) {
         obj.value = Number(obj.value);
    });
});
```

This modifies uses reduce to iterate over all array elements *except the first*. It can be expanded to check the value converted to number is a number:

```
data_p.forEach( function(a) {
    a.reduce( function( ignore, obj) {
         var temp = Number(obj.value);
         if( !isNaN(temp) {
              obj.value = temp;
         }
    });
});
```

E.G. Using `array.map` to create a new array and content arrays

```
var newArray = data_p.map( a => a.map( (o,i)=>(
    { key: o.key,
      value: o.key=="Device_Model" ? o.value : +o.value}
)));
```

Unlike the first example this method does not mutate `data_p` (or objects within it) and assumes data_p contains valid entries.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using i<6, why not d.length?

However, I'm not sure what is being accomplished or why. The end result seems to be that with your code values are converted from strings to numbers, but it is not obvious why.